# Sending ID from HTML to Flask Python

Tags: python, flask, blogs

I am beginner about Flask - Python. Now I am creating the comment function. In code below, I can list all comments for a blog or something like that. But now, I want to create button for deleting each blog. Please advise me how I can send `blog_id` (now saved as `user_comment._id`) to server and how to request it on the server.

```
       {% for user_comment in user_comments %}
            <form action="{{ url_for('comments.del_comment') }}" method="post">
                <ul class="comments-list">
                    <li class="comment">
                        <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                            <img class="avatar" src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" alt="avatar">
                        </a>
                        <div class="comment-body">
                            <div class="comment-heading">
                                <h4 class="user">{{ user_comment.email }}</h4>
                                <h5 class="time">{{ user_comment.created_date }}</h5>
                            </div>
                            <p>{{ user_comment.comment }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
           </form>
       {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you can store the id of each comment in a data-attribute of the button. Then you define a route like `'/comments/<id>/delete/'` to delete the comment. To prevent comments from getting deleted just by calling the URL in your browser I suggest to limit the route to DELETE methods only and call it via ajax request.

So add the following route to your views.py

```
@main.route('/comments/<comment_id>/delete', methods=['DELETE'])
def delete_comment(comment_id):
    comment = Comment.query.get(comment_id)
    if comment is None:
        return jsonify(
            status='error', message='no comment with id {}'.format(comment_id))
    db.session.delete(comment)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify(status='ok')
```

Your delete buttons should look like this:

```
<button href="" class="btn btn-primary delete_comment" data-id="{{ user_comment.id }}/>
```

In your template add a small ajax request:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};

    // Delete comment
    $('.delete_comment').click(function(event) {
      var comment_id = $(this).data('id');
      var url = $SCRIPT_ROOT + '/comments/' + comment_id + '/delete';
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'DELETE',
      }).done(function(data) {
        location.reload();
      });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: dear friend, thanks your your suggestion. I just finish with ajax

Answer (score 0):

> Give the button a name and value :

```
<input type="submit" name ="btn1" value="delete_blog " class="btn btn-primary" />
```

> Call the button with flask like so:

```
def delete_blog():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['btn1'] == 'delete_blog':
            pass # do something
        else:
            pass # do something else
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('blog.html', form=form)
```

I hope that helps,the question is a bit confusing.

Comment: Sorry I not good at english. Now I have page that have many many comment. Each comment with one id that I store in databse. Now I want when I click delete button html can send id to server for processing. With each user_comment we will have id: user_comment._id, email: user_comment.email as on HTML file. But I don't know how to pass id back to server

Comment: Sorry about the delayed reply. What exactly are you going to use the user_comment._id for ? Coz if you are trying just to get rid of a comment by id then i would suggest MrLeeh answer above.